# Swift TyphoonBlockComponentFactory Error in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, typhoon, xcode6-beta5

i’m using Swift with Typhoon and Cocoapods. Everything worked well until i started to write an Integrationtest (according to the [Typhoon-Example-App Test](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-example/blob/master/PocketForecastTests/Integration/PFWeatherClientTests.m)) for my Typhoon component. I wanted to setup the `TyphoonFactory` in the Test `setUp()`  method in the same way as i did in the `AppDelegate`. When i execute the test i always get a

> TyphoonBlockComponentFactory assertIsAssembly:] + 244: ERROR: MyApp.MyAssembly is not a sub-class of TyphoonAssembly

error thrown by Typhoon (wich is using the `kindOfClass` method under the hood.) The same code is working perfectly in the `AppDelegate` and i can’t figure out whats wrong.

To verify this behavior i implemented  the `isKindOfClass` check in booth classes (see code below):

- AppDelegate -> **true**
- MyComponentTest -> **false**

Can someone pls help me further?
Thx a lot!

**PodFile**

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

target "MyApp" do
pod 'Typhoon', '2.1.0'
end

target "MyAppTests" do
pod 'Typhoon', '2.1.0'
end
```

**MyAssembly.swift**

```
public class MyAssembly : TyphoonAssembly{
    //Some definitions
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    …
    var assembly : MyAssembly = MyAssembly()
    //Always returns „true“
    println("Is type of class: \(assembly.isKindOfClass(TyphoonAssembly))")
    …
}
```

**MyComponentTest.swift**

```
import XCTest
import MyApp

class MyComponentTest: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setup()
        var assembly : MyAssembly = MyAssembly()
        //Always returns „false“!
        println("Is type of class: \(assembly.isKindOfClass(TyphoonAssembly))")

        //Error is thrown „MyApp.MyAssembly is not a sub-class of TyphoonAssembly“
        var factory : TyphoonComponentFactory = TyphoonBlockComponentFactory(assembly: assembly) as TyphoonComponentFactory
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is MyAssembly or ONETyphoonAssembly? Can you raise a GitHub issue and submit sample code? . . we're still working on Swift support.

Comment: Done: [Typhoon Issue](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/242)

Comment: Thx to TyphoonGroup i solved the problem by removing the Typhoon dependency from the PodFiles "MyAppTests" section. For more details see [Typhoon-Issue](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/242)

Answer (score 7):

**For the benefit of other users:**

As discussed over on [Typhoon's Github](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon), this error occurs when the Typhoon CocoaPod is included in both the app target as well as the test target.

As application-style tests (with TEST_HOST flag set) are now the default almost everywhere, the test target automatically inherits dependencies from the main app target. In the case of Swift, with name-spacing, things can break if they're duplicated in the test target.

Therefore the solution is to remove Typhoon, and any other of the app's dependencies from the test target as these are inherited. You can still include test-specific dependencies as follows:

```
target :tests, :exclusive => true do
   pod 'OCMockito'
   pod 'AnotherTestLibrary' #etc . . 
end
```

Comment: The same solution for OCMock.

Comment: Once again Jasper you rock! This is the correct answer and instantly solved my issue :)