# Different Assembly for Tests

Tags: swift, typhoon

I use Swift, CocoaPods and Typhoon for my project. I have some classes which provide me Webservice stuff. In my tests i want to use a different class which actually don't call the Webservice. So I thought it would be a good idea to just  use another assembly for the test where i inject the fake webservice class.

```
@objc public protocol AuthService {
    func auth(username: String!, password:String!, onSuccess: (Token!) -> (Void), onError:(NSError!) -> (Void))
}

// "real" implementation
public class AuthServiceImpl: NSObject, AuthService {
    public func auth(username: String!, password:String!, onSuccess: (Token!) -> (Void), onError:(NSError!) -> (Void)){
       // do some webservice calls
    }
}

 // "fake" implementation
public class AuthServiceTestImpl: NSObject, AuthService {
    public func auth(username: String!, password:String!, onSuccess: (Token!) -> (Void), onError:(NSError!) -> (Void)){
       // do some file readings
    }
}
```

Pods File

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target :Project, :exclusive => true do
   pod 'Typhoon', '~> 2.3.4'
end
```

The problem is that i get "Use of undeclared type 'TyphoonAssembly'" in my Assembly for the tests.
Is there are Best Practice how to inject something else in test with typhoon?

Comment: I'm not sure if I addressed '"Use of undeclared type 'TyphoonAssembly'"' in the answer? If still problems let me know. I assume you've read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382348/swift-typhoonblockcomponentfactory-error-in-xctest/25404131#25404131

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Modularizing Assemblies and is outlined in the user guide [here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Modularizing-Assemblies).

The key concepts are:

- You define recipes to build instances in an assembly. Some of these instance may refer to objects defined in another assembly. For example our view controller that depends on a service client.
- To refer to objects that will come from another assembly simply create a property of the type of that assembly. Eg `TyphoonAssembly<MyProtocol>` or `MyAssemblyType*`.
- Typhoon always proxies references to collaborating assemblies. The concrete realization is provided at startup time. You can provide an alternative implementation of the protocol or a sub-class.

To bootstrap Typhoon for tests:

```
let applicationAssembly = ApplicationAssembly()
let networkComponents = TestNetworkComponents()
TyphoonAssemblyActivator.withAssemblies([
    applicationAssembly, 
    networkComponents]).activate()

//This view controller will now be injected with test network components. 
let controller = assembly.viewController() as MyViewController
```

Good practice: If you wish to reuse the above assembly in several different test classes, create a method for that to avoid duplication.

Alternatively you may wish to patch a single component, which is outlined in the [integration testing guide](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Integration-Testing).

Comment: Answer assumes Typhoon 3.0. Typhoon 2.0 style (which still works on Typhoon 3.0) is slightly different. I showed 3.0 style (assembly activator) because its nicer. . . let me know if all clear.